# React footer components display on top of each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm making my portfolio website with React + Tailwind CSS and I have a problem with components in the page overlapping.

The footer always displays on top of the other elements in my responsive layout.

For example:

[image]

**My footer component:**

```
import React from "react";
import { FaLinkedin } from "react-icons/fa";
import { SiGmail } from "react-icons/si";
import { VscGithub } from "react-icons/vsc";

export default function Footer() {
  return (
    <footer className="pt-9">
        <div className="flex flex-col m-auto justify-between w-[192px] h-[102px]">
          <div className="flex justify-between">
            <a target="_blank" href="https://github.com/Ali-Eldeba">
              <VscGithub className="cursor-pointer text-[2rem] text-[#333] transition ease-in-out hover:scale-125 hover:rotate-[10deg] dark:text-white" />
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/alieldeba/">
              <FaLinkedin className="cursor-pointer text-[2rem] text-[#0077b5] transition ease-in-out hover:scale-125 hover:rotate-[5deg]" />
            </a>
            <a target="_blank" href="mailto:alieldeba375@gmail.com">
              <SiGmail className="cursor-pointer text-[2rem] text-red-500 transition ease-in-out hover:scale-125 hover:rotate-[5deg]" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p className="text-center dark:text-white mt-[-3rem]">
          Made with <span className="text-red-500">❤</span> by alieldeba &copy;
          {new Date().getFullYear()}
        </p>
    </footer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you please add code of the parent component. on which the footer is overlaped . and How both are related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in page component it is not in the **footer** the page was having a 100vh size so the content was overlapping it
So i tried to give it ad min-h-screen in tailwind which is min-height: 100vh; in css

Answer (score 0):

looks like a css, z-index or position issue to me, I don't know how tawilnd works with this, I've never used it, try this.

```
<div>
    <p className="text-center dark:text-white mt-[-3rem]">
     Made with <span className="text-red-500">❤</span> by alieldeba &copy;
     {new date().getFullYear()}
    </p>
</div>
```